# React - How do I pass a search criteria object from my component to its epic while fetching data from service?

Tags: redux-observable

I am working on an application using React with Redux Observable.
I have a react Component which builds a seachCriteria object taking inputs from users (Dropdown, date picker).

On Click of a button I call a service which is part of an Epic.
I want to pass this search Criteria Object as a body parameter in my fetch request.

What's the best way to do that. Since epic takes an action and a store, shall I add that search criteria object as a part of store (my state object) ?

Answer (score 0):

> On Click of a button I call a service which is part of an Epic. I want to pass this search Criteria Object as a body parameter in my fetch request.

Since [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/) plugs into redux, you should be dispatching an [action](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) rather than calling a service directly.

By doing that you could add your *search criteria* to the action payload and your epic would look like:

```js
const searchEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType('search'),
  pluck('payload'),
  map(toQueryString),
  mergeMap(query => fetch(`api.something.com/search?${query}`)),
  mergeMap(result => result.json()),
  map(data => ({ type: 'search resolved', payload: data })),
);
```